# How to use filter with conditionals inside?

Tags: javascript

I tried apply chain of conditionals inside `filter. How to join result from previous conditionals and pass result the next:

```
this.fltRooms = this.rooms.filter(room => {
      let _rule;
      if (formValues["auditoryNumber"]) {
        _rule = formValues["auditoryNumber"] == room.title;
      }

      if (formValues["floor"]) {
        _rule = formValues["floor"] == room.floor; // Should be AND
      }

      if (formValues["corpus"]) {
        _rule = formValues["corpus"] == room.building; // Should be AND
      }

      return _rule;
    });
```

So, logic is, if exist `formValues["auditoryNumber"]` and `formValues["floor"]` and  `formValues["corpus"]` then filter by all three conditionals with `AND` between.

Comment: also would great to provide sample array flitrooms

Comment: Is it possible that no filters are set? And if no filters set should it return all or none?

Comment: Seems like all you need is `_rule = _rule && ...` and also initialize `_rule` to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to say if the filter is not set that it is true. If the filter is set than check out if the value matches.

```
this.fltRooms = this.rooms.filter(room => 
  (!formValues["auditoryNumber"] || formValues["auditoryNumber"] == room.title) &&
  (!formValues["floor"] || formValues["floor"] == room.floor) &&
  (!formValues["corpus"] || formValues["corpus"] == room.building)
)
```

Other way with ifs would be using the boolean in each check

```
this.fltRooms = this.rooms.filter(room => {
  let _rule = true
  if (formValues["auditoryNumber"]) {
    _rule = formValues["auditoryNumber"] == room.title;
  }

  if (_rule && formValues["floor"]) {
    _rule = formValues["floor"] == room.floor; // Should be AND
  }

  if (_rule && formValues["corpus"]) {
    _rule = formValues["corpus"] == room.building; // Should be AND
  }

  return _rule;
});
```

Comment: I prefer second way with boolean, thnak you

Answer (score 3):

And what if either doesn't exist?

As you describe it, it should be quite straightforward. Something like

```
this.fltRooms = this.rooms.filter(room =>
    formValues["auditoryNumber"] == room.title
    && formValues["floor"] == room.floor
    && formValues["corpus"] == room.building);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @bipll correct answer, using a defined array of keys to compare

```
this.filtRooms = this.rooms.filter(x => [
    'auditoryNumber',
    'floor',
    'corpus',
 ].every(y => x[y] === formValues[y]));
```

---

If keys are different on both objects to compare

```
this.filtRooms = this.rooms.filter(x => [
    [
      'auditoryNumber',
      'title',
    ],
    [
      'floor',
      'floor',
    ],
    [
      'corpus',
      'building',
    ],
  ].every(([
    key1,
    key2,
  ]) => x[key1] === void 0 || x[key1] === formValues[key2]));
```

Comment: keys aren't same in each object

Comment: @charlietfl If people are reading this : use every if you want all keys to match, use some if you want only one key to match. I think OP want all keys to match

Comment: re-reading the key needs to exist in `formValues` to be considered as filter. So what should also check in every is if it exists. Not well explained in question

Answer (score 0):

```
this.filterRooms = this.rooms.filter(meetsSearchParams);

    function meetsSearchParams(room){
      return  room.auditoryNumber == formValues["auditoryNumber"] &&
              room.floor == formValues["floor"] &&
              room.corpus == formValues["corpus"];
    }
```

For the sake of keeping this as readable as possible.

Comment: I will not work, cause I dont have formValues parameters all time

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that in your question then. Thought you were just trying to check multiple conditions inside a filter. Are the inputs always there, just they don't necessarily have value?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to need to extend it, make a map array between the two structures

```
var fields = [
  {f: "auditoryNumber", p: "title"},
  {f: "floor", p: "floor"},
  {f: "corpus", p: "building"}
];

this.fltRooms = this.rooms.filter(room => 
  fields.every(field => !formValues[field.f] || formValues[field.f] == room[field.p]);
)
```